# how to get data from database by sending a list?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring

Could someone help me out ow to get data from a table in the database by sending a list.
`

```
List<CampaignStructure> campIdList = new ArrayList<>();  try {
        JSONArray clientjson = new JSONArray(campaignids);
        Set<Long> list = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < clientjson.length(); i++){
            list.add(Long.parseLong(clientjson.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")));
        }
        for(Long id: list){
            CampaignStructure c = new CampaignStructure();
            c.setCampaignId(id);
            campIdList.add(c);
        }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
      }
```

Here **campaignids** contains list of ids (can contain duplicates).
**campIdList** contains distinct ids. i want to send these ids and get the data from database.

Comment: Have you written any code to do with databases?

Answer (score 0):

findByCampaignIdIn(List campIdList) should work.

You can find all list of JPA repository keywords can be found in the [current documentation listing.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

It shows that IsIn is equivalent – if you prefer the verb for readability – and that JPA also supports NotIn and IsNotIn.